# Bivariate Distribution for Milstein Scheme

Tags: conditional-probability, covariance, joint-distribution, bivariate

> I am seeking a density for $$Y_{t+1}\mid Y_{t},$$

where $$Y_{t}=\begin{pmatrix}Y_{t}^1\\
Y_{t}^2
 \end{pmatrix},$$

and for $i=1,2$, the $i$th component of the 2-dimensional [Milstein scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method#Description) is given by

[image]

where $$a=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\
a_{2}
 \end{pmatrix}$$ consists of the drift coefficients (constants),

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1,1} & b_{1,2}\\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}$$ is the diffusion matrix (constants); for $j=1,2$ the increments $\Delta W_{t}^j$ are given by $$\Delta W_{t}^j = W_{t+1}^{j} - W_{t}^{j}\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \Delta t\right),$$ and the increments $\Delta t$ are constant.

**Remark:** Based on the orange and blue terms, the (univariate) density of $Y_{t+1}^{i}\mid Y_{t}^i$ is a noncentral chi-squared distribution.

1. How can I used the mixed terms appearing in these expressions in order to understand the dependence of $Y_{t+1}^1$ and $Y_{t+1}^2$?
2. Are there any methods for determining a bivariate distribution (other than recognizing it as a transformation of a known distribution)?

Comment: What are the partial derivative terms? Are they known constants? are they random variables? Please be very precise about defining all terms.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins They are constants, the univariate version b'= db/dy is given on page 3 (2nd equation) of https://www.nuff.ox.ac.uk/economics/papers/1998/milpaper.pdf The main part of the distribution is determined by the increments of W in blue and orange.